# Ember-cli addons and helpers

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

What is the correct way of placing your helper files and also where should they go with respect to the resolver finding them from an addon ember-cli project?

I am running ember-cli 0.2.2.

I generated an helper from an addon project with:

```
ember g helper display-helper
```

The generator placed the file in `app/helpers` which seemed wrong to me, I would have thought that it should have been placed in `addon` helpers. I moved the file to `addon/helpers` and it looks like this:

```
export default Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('displayHelper', function displayHelper(searchPath) {
  return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString(get(this, searchPath));
});
```

When I ran `ember test` I get the following output:

> ✘ Error: Assertion Failed: A helper named 'displayHelper' could not be
>   found

The only way I get this helper to be found by the resolver is to add an import that references the helper in a component that is using it like this:

```
import displayHelper from '../helpers/display-helper';
```

This does not seem correct, I would have thought the resolver would have found this automatically?

Also even if I have the reference, the following code ends up with the same error message as above:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var get = Ember.get;

function displayHelper(context, searchPath) {
  return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString(get(context, searchPath));
}

export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(displayHelper);
```

So to sum up, I have to have this line in the component whose template uses the helper:

```
import displayHelper from '../helpers/display-helper';
```

And I have to use `registerBoundHelper` and not `makeBoundHelper` like the docs say or the helper cannot be found.

Answer (score 3):

If you move your helper from app/helpers to addon/helpers, it is not available in your app namespace. To fix this, add the following file:

```
// app/helpers/display-helper.js

import displayHelper from 'your-addon-name/helpers/display-helper";
export default displayHelper;
```

(Do not copy your-addon-name literally, use the name of your addon, which is also your addon's namespace.)

This is based on the instructions here:

http://www.ember-cli.com/#addon-components

Just like the example component there, you can put your real helper code in addons/helpers/display-helper, but you need to import and reexport it to your app for your resolver to find it.

Comment: I've already tried this sadly, no files are getting automatically loaded in the app/folders.

0.2.2 seems to be broke in a lot of ways.

Comment: Having a very similar issue with 0.2.3 as well. Also, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29506064/ember-cli-custom-input-helper) as well as the ember-cli [docs](http://www.ember-cli.com/#resolving-handlebars-helpers) say that "it is advised to leverage Components instead."  But I'm not sure why you'd need a component to define a helper in Ember-CLI?  As a counter-example, note the structure of [this repo](https://github.com/johnotander/ember-cli-dates), although it's using an earlier version (0.2.0).

Comment: Hmmm... I don't know why it isn't working for you guys, but you can try to register your helpers manually in an initializer as should only be necessary for helpers without a dash in the name. See the trim example at http://www.ember-cli.com/#resolving-handlebars-helpers

Comment: The autoloading appears to apply only to helpers generated or placed within the application.  I have attempted to use an initializer (borrowing from the example in [this issue](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/3291)), but this hasn't worked either.  A little further down in the passage you linked to it mentions that the helper approach will not work.