# Ember CLI: custom input helper

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to extend Ember's TextField with UrlField so that if someone forgets to include `http://`, it does it for them.

Here's my View:

views/input-url.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.TextField.extend({

    type: 'url',

    didInsertElement: function() {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        this.formatValue();
    },

    onValueChange: function() {
        this.formatValue();
    }.observes('value'),

    formatValue: function() {
        var pattern = /^https{0,1}:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z0-9]+/g;
        if (pattern.test(this.get('value')))
          return;

        if (!pattern.test('http://' + this.get('value')))
          return;

        this.set('value', 'http://' + this.get('value'));
    }

});
```

If I use it in my template like this, it works fine:

```
{{view "input-url" value=url}}
```

I prefer to use custom view helpers, so I created this (following the guide at the bottom of this page: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/templates/writing-helpers/):

helpers/input-url.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import InputUrl from '../views/input-url';

export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(InputUrl);
```

Now trying to render this in my template doesn't work:

```
{{input-url value=url}}
```

I've also tried different permutations of this, including what's shown in the guide `Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper('input-url', InputUrl);` (which throws an error), but I can't seem to get my input field to show up. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are doing wrong with your view helper, but there is a much simpler solution: take advantage of the fact that Ember.Textfield is a component. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TextField.html

Simply move views/input-url.js to components/input-url.js and get rid of your view helper.

Then `{{input-url value=url}}` should work automatically.

Answer (score 2):

If you want do to this using a helper, you cannot extend [Ember.TextField](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TextField.html) because extends [Ember.Component](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html) and is not a Handlebars helper.

The way to do this using a helper would actually be simpler. Since you are using Ember-CLI, you can create a helper called **"input-url"** with the command `ember g helper input-url` and the only code you would need is the code within your `formatValue()` function:

*helpers/input-url.js*

```
// define patter globally so it's not recreated each time the function is called    
var pattern = /^https{0,1}:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z0-9]+/g;

export function inputUrl(value) {
    if (pattern.test(value)) {
        return value;
    }

    if (!pattern.test('http://' + value)) {
        return value;
    }

    return 'http://' + value;
};

export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(inputUrl);
```

And you can use it like:

```
{{input-url PASS_YOUR_URL_HERE}}
```

Where the value you pass will be the value of the `value` variable within the helper.

You could also create a component, as **@Gaurav** suggested, using the exact code you have above, just in *components/input-url.js* instead and delete the helper cause it is not necessary anymore. You also have to edit the corresponding template of the component if you want it to display the `value` with a single handlebars expression:

*templates/components/input-url.hbs*

```
{{value}}
```

The usage with a component would be:

```
{{input-url value=PASS_YOUR_URL_HERE}}
```